# textbox enable disable on combo box select

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to enable and disable a text box based on the selected value of a combo box. I am able to enable but unable to disable.

```
if(IsPostBack)
{                
    if (cmbPujaName.SelectedValue == "DONATION")
    {
        txtAmount.Enabled = true;
    }
    if(cmbPujaName.SelectedValue != "DONATION")
    {
         txtAmount.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The combo box contains the series of values pulled up from the database. AutoPostBack is enabled for combo box.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Working just fine when I test this exact code. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I changed the cmbPujaName.SelectedValue to cmbPujaName.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(). It works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (cmbPujaName.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim() == "DONATION")
            {
                txtAmount.Enabled = true;
            }
            if (cmbPujaName.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim() != "DONATION")
            {
                txtAmount.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. After assigning value to textbox use this to either enable/disable it.

```
txtAmount.Attributes.Add("readonly","true"); //To disable
txtAmount.Attributes.Add("readonly","false"); //To enable
```

Comment: I changed the cmbPujaName.SelectedValue to cmbPujaName.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(). It works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is that your code is in if(isPostBack) my guess is that you set 
the combo box to auto post back true, if so you dont get in the first "if" if my guess is worng please send markup so we can look at it.

Comment: I changed the cmbPujaName.SelectedValue to cmbPujaName.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(). It works now. Thank you